# java ee jpa eclipselink foreign key is null in child table

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, java-ee-7

I am using JavaEE with JPA, eclipselink and postgres. I want to set Id of parent and child entity without calling `nextval` for database sequence.

My old code was :

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
public class Parent{

    // Use the sequence that is defined above:
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq")
    @Id long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
public class Child{

    // Use the sequence that is defined above:
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq")
    @Id long id;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn()
    Parent parent;

}
```

If i persist 1000 parent with 1000 children for each parent,1001000 query of `nextVal('seq')` will be executed which slows down my work.

So i try this :

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
public class Parent{

    @Column(insertable=false,columnDefinition="integer not null default (nextval'seq'::regclass)")
    @Id long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
public class Child{

    @Column(insertable=false,columnDefinition="integer not null default (nextval'seq'::regclass)")
    @Id long id;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn()
    Parent parent;

}
```

No query was exceuted from JPA to find `nextval`.It works fine with parent and child id but forgin key of child always set to null.

How can i solve this problem ? I just do not want JPA to call `nextval` each time.

Comment: How are you persisting the data in the second case you tried? Please post the code.

Comment: Use a sequence that allows preallocation of more than 1 value at a time.  Set your sequence to allocate 1000 at a time, allowing JPA to fetch only once for your batches of 1000.  see http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html

Comment: both cases have the same way in persisting data this is the ' for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){ Parent p = new Parent(); for(int j =0;j<1000;j++){Child c = new Child(); c.setParent(p); p.getChildrend().add(child})} em.merge(p);}'